# Insert Image file in mysql database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am working C# with 3 tier architecture. I have to insert image file using MySQL stored procedure. Here i am converting image file into byte array. but i cant insert directly as bytes.

```
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
string stbytes = ByteArrayToString(bytes);
```

So again I convert bytes as a string and insert into the data base.

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    return hex.Replace("-", "");
}
string result = objBL.InsertBankAttachmentBL(filename, contenttype, stbytes); //insert
```

Now I can save word document. but i cant insert image file. The following exception arrives while inserting an image file.

> Data too long for column 'iattach_file' at row 2

My DAC Layer here:

```
string sqlCommand = "sp_F1_fileUpload";
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand);

// Retrieve products from the specified category.
 db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "ioption", DbType.String,"insert");
 db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "iattach_id", DbType.Int32, 0);
 db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "iattach_name", DbType.String, iattach_name);
 db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "iattach_extension", DbType.String, iattach_extension);
 db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "iattach_file", DbType.String, iattach_file);
```

In Stored Procedure I use "Blob" datatype to save "iattach_file".

Need help to find out the solution.

My screen here:

[image]

Comment: What is the type of your iattach_file column? How much data can it handle? Please show us the code of your stored procedure.

Comment: In code i use "string" data type. in Stored procedure i use "blob" data type @msporek

Comment: If you are using blob field save it as byte array

Comment: You should use a System.Byte[] type for a blob. And a different DbType, check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Did you check this thread? http://deepak-sharma.net/2012/11/28/how-to-save-images-in-mysql-database-using-c-sharp-in-windows-forms-application/

Comment: when i use byte array directly,i got the following error "Cannot convert byte[] to byte". @Damith

Comment: Can you show me code section which gives the error

Comment: I have attached my screen. @Damith

Comment: `InsertBankAttachmentBl` third parameter is string but you are passing byte array. That gives you the first error

Comment: If i use byte data type in InsertBankAttachmentBl , then i get the following error "cannot convert from Byte[] to byte. I don't know that which data type should be used for byte array. @Damith

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67909/discussion-between-damith-and-kani).